# WPF Access datagrid in tabs

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have a templated tabcontrol with templated datagrids in each tab, like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>
        ....
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid>

                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    ...
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    ...
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I omitted data bindings in the code so it reads better.

I want to specify a tab, and a cell in the datagrid (row and column) and after clicking a button make the program open the specified tag and scroll down through the table to highlight the specified cell automatically, similar to what is done in visual studio when you click on a compile error and it takes you to the line in the file where the error is.

I am changing the selected tab with Tab.SelectedIndex, and that works, but I can't access the datagrid inside of the tab because it is only generated when the tab is clicked manually. I tried using Load but it doesn't work. How can I generate and access the datagrid inside each tab?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because it's being loaded asynchronously? Try using performing your grid selection after loading using the Loaded event.

```
TabItem selectedTab = MyTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
selectedTab.Loaded+= delegate { //select grid row };

//or if this works, I'm sure it would have been initialized in the process of being selected?
TabItem selectedTab = MyTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
selectedTab.MyGrid...
```

Or maybe selectedTab.Initialized.

The tab items are also children of the tabControl, so you should be able to access them using Children[index] as TabItem

Comment: I can't even access the tab I don't know how to do it with templates.

Comment: "I am changing the selected tab with Tab.SelectedIndex, and that works, but I can't access the datagrid inside of the tab" can you put the code for this to show what you're trying to do a bit more?

Comment: I named my TabControl like this:

            <TabControl   x:Name="MyTabControl">

After that I selected the tab in code-behind like this:

MyTabControl.SelectedIndex = theIndexIWant;

But I don't know how to get the content of the tab I just selected, because it is not yet loaded.

Comment: You're setting the ItemsSource of the tab control and they're dynamically created? Try using MyTabControl.SelectedItem